# Convert decimal day to HH:MM

Tags: r, date, datetime, time, format

I have a vector of decimal numbers, which represent 'decimal day', the fraction of a day. I want to convert it into HH:MM format using R.

For example, the number `0.8541667` would correspond to `20:30`. How can I convert the numbers to `HH:MM` format?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this:

```
R> format(as.POSIXct(Sys.Date() + 0.8541667), "%H:%M", tz="UTC")
[1] "20:30"
R>
```

We start with a date--which can be any date, so we use today--and add your desired fractional day.

We then convert the Date type into a Datetime object.

Finally, we format the hour and minute part of the Datetime object, ensuring that UTC is used for the timezone.

Comment: Alternatively: `format(.POSIXct(86400*0.8541667, "UTC"), "%H:%M")`.

Answer (score 18):

Using `chron`:

```
chron::times(0.8541667)
#[1] 20:30:00
```

Answer (score 2):

One option with data.table:

```
> library(data.table)
> structure(as.integer(0.4305556*60*60*24), class="ITime")
[1] "10:20:00"
```

We convert from day fraction to seconds since midnight; coerce to integer; and apply ITime class. (ITime works with integer-stored seconds since midnight.)

Other resources:

- @GaborGrothendieck re chron package and link to his R News article with Thomas Petzoldt about converting from Excel in particular [Converting a time decimal/fraction representing days to its actual time in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41941523/converting-a-time-decimal-fraction-representing-days-to-its-actual-time-in-r)
- @JorisChau re RStudio's hms package [how to convert excel internal coding for hours to hours in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57482012/how-to-convert-excel-internal-coding-for-hours-to-hours-in-r?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 0):

If you are converting the decimals in a dataframe and there are `NULL`s in the column, `times` function from `library(chron)` is throwing an error. Alternatively, you can use `library(openxlsx)` and `library(hms)`.

```
library(openxlsx)
library(hms)

time <- 0.8541667
time1 <- convertToDateTime(time)
time2 <- as_hms(format(time1, "%H:%M:%S"))
```