# Converting a time decimal/fraction representing days to its actual time in R?

Tags: r, time-format, datetime-conversion

I have a column in R on my dataset with values that have been converted into what I believe is a time decimal fraction based on *days*. I have been using this site as a reference: http://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/time/decimal-to-time-calculator.php

Which converting 0.3408565 *days* corresponds to the time of 8:10:50 by doing the following:

```
0.3408565 * 24 hours/day = 8.180555544 = 8 hours

0.180555544 * 60 minutes = 10.83333264 = 10 minutes

0.83333264 * 60 seconds = 49.9999584 = 50 seconds
```

As you can see it is extracting the remainder and doing further multiplication, however I'm not sure how I could implement the process within R. I want to convert all the values in my column using this so I can replace 0.3408565, 0.3864468, 0.4400231 etc with their actual time counterparts 8:10:50, 09:16:29, 10:33:38 respectively. This seems to be how it is done in Excel too.

I tried writing my own function which in English does:

```
convertTime <- function(x)
{
x * 60 = Hour
x2 * 24 = Min
x3 * 24 = Sec

hourChar <- as.character(Hour)
minChar <- as.character(Min)
secChar <- as.character(Sec)
paste(hourChar, minChar, secChar, sep=":")
}
```

With x being 0.3408565, but of course this doesn't extract the remainder. I might be seriously overcomplicating it, but I want to loop through all values in the column using each value as input to convert.

Lastly, I have looked at packages such as 'lubridate' but cannot find anything that is relevant to my problem.

I also browsed here for my specific situation but couldn't find anything really relevant to my problem. Is there any package or solution that could help me?

**EDIT:** I want to say both answers work perfectly for anyone else having this kind of problem, thank you to you both!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a custom function

```
convertTime <- function(x){
    Hour = (x * 24) %% 24 #For x>1, only the value after decimal will be considered
    Minutes = (Hour %% 1) * 60
    Seconds = (Minutes %% 1) * 60

    hrs = ifelse (Hour < 10, paste("0",floor(Hour),sep = ""), as.character(floor(Hour)))
    mins = ifelse (Minutes < 10, paste("0",floor(Minutes),sep = ""), as.character(floor(Minutes)))    
    secs = ifelse (Seconds < 10, paste("0",round(Seconds,0),sep = ""), as.character(round(Seconds,0)))

    return(paste(hrs, mins, secs, sep = ":"))
}
```

**USAGE**

```
a = seq(0,1,0.2)
convertTime(a)
#[1] "00:00:00" "04:48:00" "09:36:00" "14:24:00" "19:12:00" "00:00:00"

b = 0.3408565
convertTime(b)
# [1] "08:10:50"
```

Comment: I have just tried this solution and it works perfectly for my situation, thank you ever so much! By any chance would you be aware of how a date can also be converted without asking another question for it? Again I have a date (41641) which I can convert to 02/01/2014 which I think 41641 is the number of days since 01/01/1900?

Comment: `as.Date(41641, origin = "1900-01-01")`

Comment: This is perfect thank you so much for your help, I just have to convert it to UK time which I will figure out how to do! Again thank you so much!

Comment: Great answer, but it's not rounding time to the next minute at seconds = 60. Any ideas? For example, I get this ->12:33:60

Answer (score 3):

Try `times` in chron which represents times as fractions of a day:

```
library(chron)
format(times(0.3408565))
## [1] "08:10:50"
```

If you have something like x = 3.3408565 days then this can be formatted as:

```
x <- 3.3408565
paste(x %/% 1, times(x %% 1))
## [1] "3 08:10:50"
```

Regarding the subject of the question it is not clear what an "actual time in R" means but time intervals can be expressed as `"difftime"` objects so if you want to convert `x` to a `"difftime"` class R object then:

```
as.difftime(x, units = "days")
## Time difference of 3.340857 days
```

or if you want to subtract `x` from the current date/time:

```
Sys.time() - as.difftime(x, units = "days")
## [1] "2017-01-27 05:00:22 EST"
```

There is also some  information that may be relevant in the R Help Desk column of R News 4/1 including information on converting Excel date/times in R -- https://www.r-project.org/doc/Rnews/Rnews_2004-1.pdf

Comment: I have also just tried this method and again it works perfectly for my situation, thank you ever so much!