# how to convert excel internal coding for hours to hours in R?

Tags: r, lubridate

I have a hour variable stored as excel internal coding in R. See (https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2015/06/23/excel-time-format-now-time-functions/), for example 0.4305556 is equivalent to 10:20:00 AM. How to convert 0.4305556 to 10:20:00 AM in R. After this i need to substract times to find time diferennces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `hms`:

```r
library(hms)

hms(days = 0.4305556)
#> 10:20:00.00384
```

Subtract two `hms` objects to return a `difftime` object with the time difference in seconds:

```r
hms(days = 0.5) - hms(days = 0.25)
#> Time difference of 21600 secs
```

Or to get the time difference in a different unit use the `difftime` function:

```r
difftime(hms(days = 0.5), hms(days = 0.25), units = "hours")
#> Time difference of 6 hours
```